# Functions and a GUI for entropy-related calculations

Tags: python, object-oriented, design-patterns

I wrote a script with utilities for calculating the entropy of iterables and included a Tk GUI that shows a quick overview over a text's properties in real-time. ([on GitHub](https://github.com/TidB/entropy))

I tried to follow PEP 8 as good as possible, but I'm not sure about other things, specificially:

1. I think my docstrings are sometimes overly redundant, see the GUI for example.
2. In `gui.py`, I'm not sure if I should move the `calculate` method out of the `GUI` class.
3. Is the overall design good? I know it's a rather small project, but I want to do this correctly.

If you have any other concerns beside these questions, I'm open to criticism!

The code is split into two modules:

**calc.py** - Includes the calculation functions

```
"""Utilities for entropy-related calculations."""


from math import ceil as _ceil, log2 as _log2


def prob_to_info(probability):
    """Converts probability in the range from 0 to 1 into information measured
    in bits, therefore using the dual logarithm. Returns None if the probability
    is equal to zero."""
    if probability == 0:
        return None
    elif probability == 1:
        return 0
    else:
        return -_log2(probability)


def info_to_prob(information):
    """Converts information measured in bits to probablity."""
    return 2**-information


def entropy(iterable):
    """Calculates the Shannon entropy of the given iterable."""
    return sum(prob[1]*prob_to_info(prob[1]) for prob in char_mapping(iterable))


def optimal_bits(iterable):
    """Calculates the optimal usage of bits for decoding the iterable."""
    return _ceil(entropy(iterable)) * len(iterable)


def metric_entropy(iterable):
    """Calculates the metric entropy of the iterable."""
    return entropy(iterable) / len(iterable)


def char_mapping(iterable):
    """Creates a dictionary of the unique chararacters and their probability
    in the given iterable."""
    char_map = dict.fromkeys(set(iterable))
    for char in set(iterable):
        probability = iterable.count(char) / len(iterable)
        char_map[char] = probability

    return sorted(char_map.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
```

**gui.py**

```
import tkinter as tk

import calc


class GUI:
    """A simple Tk-based interface for real-time entropy-related analytics
    on given texts."""

    def __init__(self, root):
        """Initializes the GUI where 'root' is a tkinter.Tk instance."""
        self.parent = root
        self.parent.state("zoomed")

        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.parent)
        self.frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nwes")

        self.input_head = tk.Label(self.frame, text="Input:")
        self.input_head.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nwes")
        self.ignore_case_value = tk.IntVar()
        self.ignore_case_value.trace("w", self.case_switch)
        self.ignore_case = tk.Checkbutton(
            self.frame,
            variable=self.ignore_case_value,
            text="Ignore case"
        )
        self.ignore_case.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nwes")
        self.input_main = tk.Text(self.frame)
        self.input_main.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="nwes", columnspan=2)
        self.input_main.bind("<KeyRelease>", self.update)

        self.output_head = tk.Label(self.frame, text="Output:")
        self.output_head.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky="nwes")
        self.output_main = tk.Text(self.frame, state=tk.DISABLED)
        self.output_main.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky="nwes")

        self.parent.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.parent.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.frame.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.frame.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.frame.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)

    def case_switch(self, *_):
        """Toggles case sensivity ."""
        self.input_main.edit_modified(True)
        self.update()

    def update(self, *_):
        """Updates the contents of the analysis text box."""
        if not self.input_main.edit_modified():
            return

        analyze_text = self.calculate()
        self.output_main["state"] = tk.NORMAL
        self.output_main.delete("1.0", tk.END)
        self.output_main.insert("1.0", analyze_text)
        self.output_main["state"] = tk.DISABLED
        self.input_main.edit_modified(False)

    def calculate(self, *_):
        """Creates the analysis text."""
        text = self.input_main.get("1.0", "end-1c")
        if self.ignore_case_value.get():
            text = text.lower()
        char_map = calc.char_mapping(text)

        entropy = calc.entropy(char_map)
        metric_entropy = calc.metric_entropy(text)
        optimal = calc.optimal_bits(text)

        info = "\n".join(
            [
                "Length: " + str(len(text)),
                "Unique chars: " + str(len(char_map)),
                "Entropy: " + str(entropy),
                "Metric entropy: " + str(metric_entropy),
                "Optimal bit usage: " + str(optimal)
            ]
        )

        table_head = " Char\t| Probability\t\t| Bits\t\t| Occurences"
        table_body = "\n".join(
            [
                " " + repr(char)[1:-1] +
                "\t" + str(round(prob, 7)) +
                "\t\t" + str(round(calc.prob_to_info(prob), 7)) +
                "\t\t" + str(text.count(char))
                for char, prob in char_map
            ]
        )
        table = "\n".join([table_head, table_body])

        return "\n\n".join([info, table])


def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    _ = GUI(root)
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Why do you alias `ceil` and `log2`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You ask about docstrings, so you should be aware that there is [a PEP for those, too](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/). In particular, note that:

> Multi-line docstrings consist of a summary line just like a one-line docstring, followed by a blank line, followed by a more elaborate description.

The [style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) specifies that docstring lines should be a maximum of 72 characters; a few of yours exceed this. There are various formats that you can adopt to include information in the docstrings in a structured way for use by documentation generators and other tools; I like [the Google style](http://sphinxcontrib-napoleon.readthedocs.org/en/latest/example_google.html).

For example,

```
"""Converts probability in the range from 0 to 1 into information measured
in bits, therefore using the dual logarithm. Returns None if the probability
is equal to zero."""
```

could be more like:

```
"""Converts probability into information, measured in bits.

Notes:
  Uses the dual logarithm.

Args:
  probability (float): In the range from 0 to 1.

Returns:
  float [or None if the probability is equal to zero].

"""
```

---

I assume that you've aliased `log2` and `ceil` to `_log2` and `_ceil` respectively to avoid them being `import`ed into `gui`. Instead, you can use `__all__` to specify what should be available to modules that import from `calc` (see [the tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html)):

```
__all__ = [
    'entropy',
    'info_to_prob',
    'metric_entropy',
    'optimal_bits',
    'prob_to_info',
]
```

---

It seems a bit odd to have the class that occupies pretty much the whole of `gui.py` be explicitly ignored after instantiation! Rather than having:

```
root = tk.Tk()
_ = GUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

you could make the `GUI` class inherit from `tk.Tk`:

```
class GUI(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.state("zoomed")

        self.frame = tk.Frame(self)
        ...
```

and run it directly:

```
root = GUI()
root.mainloop()
```

This is trivial enough to include under `if __name__ == '__main__':` directly, rather than via `main`. There's also no need for the `, *_` in `GUI.calculate`.

---

Rather than the string concatenation with `+`, I would use [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format), for example:

```
    table_head = " Char | Probability |     Bits    | Occurrences "
    table_body = "\n".join(
        [
            " {:<4} | {:>11.7f} | {:>11.7f} | {:>11}".format(
                char, 
                prob, 
                calc.prob_to_info(prob), 
                text.count(char)
            )
            for char, prob in char_map
        ]
    )
```

Given what this method does, I don't think that `calculate` is an appropriate name for it. You could split the calculations and the formatting into two methods, with more appropriate names.

---

As currently implemented, the code breaks (due to `ZeroDivisionError` in `metric_entropy`) if you toggle **Ignore Case** before entering any text, or if you delete all of the input text. You should handle this error, and display something sensible in these cases.

Answer (score 5):

As you never use the first element of the tuples you get from `char_mapping`, and the order does not count I wrote a simpler function:

```
def ratios(iterable):
    """
    Returns a list of ratios indicating how often the chars
    appear in the iterable.

    >>> list(sorted(ratios("hello")))
    [0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4]
    """
    return [iterable.count(i) / len(iterable) for i in set(iterable)]
```

that you can use as:

```
def entropy(iterable):
    """Calculates the Shannon entropy of the given iterable.

    >>> entropy(range(10))
    3.321928094887362
    >>> entropy([1,2,3])
    1.584962500721156
    """
    return sum(prob*prob_to_info(prob) for prob in ratios(iterable))
```

obtaining the same results as before.

Comment: Though it's actually used to create the char table in the GUI, I think you're right as it isn't used elsewhere. I think I'll create the complete table with chars and stuff in the GUI then.